# how to copy text from linux to windows when using putty ssh to linux?

Tags: ssh, putty

when I select a text and right click in an putty session to linux terminal, it echos back the selected test to terminal and then copies to clipboard, 
how can I prevent the copied to clipboard test to be echoed in the linux terminal ?

Comment: Right-click pastes the current clipboard content. Be careful with it, it could contain unintended command that may result in data loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you select text in putty it is automatically copied to the clipboard, no right click needed.

Comment: As a clarification: it is the very _act_ of selecting any text in a putty shell that copies it to the clipboard. As pointed out in a comment on the OP, right-clicking pastes from the clipboard. [Here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.1.1) is the corresponding text in the putty manual.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to copy text in the putty window the same way you would in a Windows command prompt window. They don't work the same.

In the putty window, just click and drag the mouse to select the text that you want. Do not right-click afterwards. The text is copied to the clipboard when you finish selecting. Right-click in a putty window is the *paste* operation, which is causing the echo behavior that you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

In the putty configuration window go to Window/Selection and you can change "Action of mouse buttons" to "Windows".  This will make right-clicking work how you would expect it to work under windows and prevent accidental pastes when you right-click.